# Html with Custom font in android

Tags: android, html, fonts

I am programmatically creating a HTML file and storing the same in sdcard with custom font.

For this on first run of my android application I am storing the html file and customfont.otf in a same location (i.e inside sd card).

so my question is when I pullout the html file from sd card and open it on desktop I could not able to see the html content with my custom font.Its opening with default font of my browser.

when I copy the html file to desktop I want to open my html file with the custom font only

How can we achieve It programmatically,

Any help is always appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat I had a similar scenario, where I need to load the html content in a custom font. I stored the ttf (or otf) file in my asset folder. Then created a String CSS as

```
private final String CSS = "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyCustomFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/MyCustomFont.ttf\");}body {font-family: The-2K12;}}</style>";
```

then while loading webview, I just appended this string to html string like

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(" ",
                CSS + my_html_data,
                mime, encoding, "");
```

Hope it will be helpful...

Comment: Thanks, but my question is when I copy the html file to desktop from sd card ,I want to open my html file with the custom font only.plz read my question properly.

Comment: Will It work if we copy the html file from sd card and pull it to desktop and open it?

Comment: Sorry Raghu, I haven't understood your question correctly. If there are any issues in referencing the font in the html file, it will show error logs in browser's console. Did you check that ?

Comment: I could able to get the output in emulator.I am programmatically writing the html file to sdcard. my problem is when we copy the html from sd card to desktop and then open it its not showing the content/text with custom font.Its showing/opening with browsers default font only.

Comment: yeah that I know, am asking abt the console in the browser window ... not the emulator ?

Comment: How can we check our browser console? I m using IE browser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46524/discussion-between-heyjii-and-raghu)